# Running an external executable in Xcode 4 to use it as a debugger

Tags: c, debugging, xcode4, makefile

I have a C program which I normally compile by using Makefile on the terminal, and I would like to run my executable on Xcode 4 for debugging purposes. The graphical debugger on Xcode 4 seems extremely useful.

I read a bunch of related posts about adding external executables, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I tried two things. 
First, I started an empty project, and created a new scheme and set the executable to my executable. This failed when I build..it says "The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'new_scheme'."

Second, I tried making an External Build System project by setting the tool path to /usr/bin/make, and putting all my source file and my makefile in the project. This also failed on build..here's the error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point, but basically I would like to debug my C program using XCode 4.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you add your sources in Xcode and have Xcode do the actual build instead of using make?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried that(slapping all my source files into the project), but the build failed - it seems like all my files compiled, but the linking failed...not sure why

Comment: ld: duplicate symbol _foo in /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/p1p1-blycujwztfigyubiyoyajnkuwvai/Build/Intermediates/p1p1.build/Debug/p1p1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myfile1.o and /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/p1p1-blycujwztfigyubiyoyajnkuwvai/Build/Intermediates/p1p1.build/Debug/p1p1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myfile2.o for architecture x86_64
Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

(I modified names for privacy's sake)
This is a linker error.

Comment: Hm...it compiles and links just fine when I just run make on the terminal...could it be the xcode setting?

Comment: There's no way to help you without the actual code and the flags you're passing to the compiler.

Comment: I just found out that this whole time, I have been compiling on my school's linux computer, and if I run makefile on my mac, it won't even work on the terminal. It gives me the error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I think this means that I need to rewrite the makefile to make it work for the 64bit architecture. This is a separate problem...

Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.